# Put a child always on front when visible

Tags: actionscript-3

In my Engine class, the window "Building" is created like this :

**Engine.as**

```
private function createUI():void{
building = new Building (stage);
            addChild(building);
            building.visible = false;
```

(I've got a class named Building.as.)

Everytime I click, on my useBox (Usebox.as), on the button buy the function "buyIt" is called.

**UseBox.as**

```
 public function showBuilding():void{
    Engine.building.visible = true;
                }
```

Then I can choose the building that I want. When I chose a building the window become invisible :

**Building.as**

```
public function Construction(e:MouseEvent):void{
Engine.building.visible = false;
Engine.test.buildIt(e);
}
```

and a building appears on the scene (with the function "buildIt")

**Tower.as**

```
public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stageRef.addChild(this);
    this.visible = true;
}
```

The problem is that everytime the window "Building" is visible, the "Tower" is in front of everything !

Is there a way to say that "Building" must always be on front of everything ? (and if yes, where should I tell that ? In Engine.as ? In Building.as ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with you're code, you put every tower on the stage directly so you don't have way to manage UI in front of everything.

```
public function buildIt(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stageRef.addChild(this); //don't use the stage here.
    this.visible = true;
}
```

You should use your main class for the display of your game.

Comment: Ok, I'll put the code of my Tower.as in my Engine.as (main)